# Is there any logic for scanning qr code that will redirect to multiple websites in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

While we are scanning qr code it is redirecting to that particular website which we have mentioned in that code, but my requirement is if I even mention any URL it should redirect to that particular page like google, myntra, facebook etc...Can anyone please help me out with this ???
This is my Mainactivity.java file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Generate = findViewById(R.id.Generate);
    Scan = findViewById(R.id.Scan);
    mytext = findViewById(R.id.text);
    qr_code = findViewById(R.id.qrcode);
    Generate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = mytext.getText().toString();
            if (text != null && !text.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    MultiFormatWriter multiFormatWriter = new MultiFormatWriter();
                    BitMatrix bitMatrix = multiFormatWriter.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 500, 500);
                    BarcodeEncoder barcodeEncoder = new BarcodeEncoder();
                    Bitmap bitmap = barcodeEncoder.createBitmap(bitMatrix);
                    qr_code.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (WriterException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    Scan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);
            IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
            intentIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            intentIntegrator.setCameraId(0);
            intentIntegrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
            intentIntegrator.setPrompt("scanning");
            intentIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(true);
            intentIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
            intentIntegrator.initiateScan();
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    final IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (result != null && result.getContents() != null) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle("scan Result")
                .setMessage(result.getContents())
                .setPositiveButton("copy", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        ClipboardManager manager = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("result", result.getContents());
                        manager.setPrimaryClip(data);
                    }
                }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }).create().show();
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you explain what the contents of a QR code consist of?

Comment: it consists of URL and Text for generator and scanner . In this i used Zxing libraries

Comment: What do you mean by "mention" a URL?

Comment: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
            startActivity(browserIntent);

Comment: This the code which i have used to scan qrcode and open url